# React JS Frontend - Key Error When Rendering List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, frontend

I am getting the following error when rendering a list using ReactJS

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `DriverList`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at DriverList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:720:13)
    at div
    at Drivers (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1401:75)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47364:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47297:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46106:5)
    at App
```

So far I have tried to unsuccessfully resolve it by adding the key value to both the Driver, a higher level div than the Driver object that doesn't need to be there, adding a key to the a React Fragment wrapped around the Driver object. I have tried adding it to each of them individually as well as multiple parts. I have also tried adding the key to the li item within the actual Driver object file that populates the DriverList. I still keep getting the error and I am thinking I am making a stupid mistake somewhere along the code that someone can point out and laugh at me for.

```
import React from "react"

import Driver from "./Driver"
import Card from "../../shared/components/interface/Card"

import "./DriverList.css"

const DriverList = (props) => {
    if (props.items.length === 0) {
        return (
            <Card key='none'>
                <h2>No drivers found.</h2>
            </Card>
        )
    } else {
        // Render the List
        return (
            <ul className='driver-list'>
                {props.items.map((driver) => {
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment key={driver.id}>
                            <Driver
                                key={driver.id}
                                id={driver.id}
                                permitno={driver.permitno}
                                fname={driver.fname}
                                lname={driver.lname}
                                mailaddr1={driver.mailaddr1}
                                mailaddr2={driver.mailaddr2}
                                dateofbirth={driver.dateofbirth}
                                driversex={driver.driversex}
                                licenseidno={driver.licenseidno}
                                dvrclass={driver.dvrclass}
                                dvrpermit={driver.dvrpermit}
                                endorsemnt={driver.endorsemnt}
                                restricts={driver.restricts}
                                expdate={driver.expdate}
                                cmpldate={driver.cmpldate}
                                numpoints={driver.numpoints}
                                suspended={driver.suspended}
                                driver_status={driver.driver_status}
                            />
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default DriverList
```

Comment: This error also happens when you don't put the fragment and put the key on the driver ? Moreover are you sure every driver has a unique id ?  (if not you can also add the index in the array to the key)

Comment: You only need a key on the `React.Fragment` in this case.

Comment: Even with the key on the React.Fragment only, it still throws the error. The ID in questions is assigned when the driver is added via Mongoose to MongoDB, (they originally have the _id set, but also a 'id' set via 'getters : true'. I only have two test drivers currently, but they both have unique IDs

Comment: The fragment seems pointless here. As long as you're returning a single element (component), you don't need that.

Comment: Also, considering the sheer quantity of driver properties you're passing, why not just pass `driver`? You can then destructure the object in the Driver component as props.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
props.items.map((driver, idx) => {
                    return (
                            <Driver
                                key={idx}
```

and see if it helps. And if it does it means that driver.id repeats somewhere